# CSS pseudo :after :before Not working

Tags: css

```
<div class="select" style="">
<label>Status</label>
<select id="ticket_status_id" name="ticket[status_id]" tabindex="4">
<option value="0" selected="selected">New</option>
<option value="1">Open</option>
<option value="2">Pending</option>
<option value="3">Solved</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Hey does anyone know how I would add a `'title'` attribute to `'ticket_status_id'`? Using css I can style `'#ticket_status_id'` but when I try using `'#ticket_status_id:before'` or `'ticket_status_id:after'` with `'content: "";'` nothing happens?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add 'title' attribute to any html element using css. For this you need to use javascript.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById('ticket_status_id').title='test title'

</script>
```

Comment: One more thing, can I style this title from css? Basically I want i want a nice looking tooltip when the person hovers over ticket_status_id

Comment: latest version of jQuery UI has a new feature named Tooltip: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ . It will make pretty titles out of your title attribute.